# Using two AppBaLayout, when scrolling RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have Activity layout structure like:

```html
<DrawerLayout>
 <CoordinatorLayout>
     <AppBarLayout>
         <Toolbar app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
     </AppBarLayout>

     <fragment app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
 </CoordinatorLayout> 
</DrawerLayout>
```

Inside fragment I have:

```html
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <include layout="@layout/some_view" app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    <AppBarLayout>

    <RecyclerView app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Sample layout:

[image: Sample layout]

I would like to implement next case on scrolling RecyclerView:

1. Collapse Toolbar
2. Collapse some_view
3. Start scrolling RecyclerView

It can be easily done, if remove AppBarLayout from fragment and move some_view inside first AppBarLayout.
But I have a lot of fragments with different some_view for each fragment, and I would like keep all fragment related stuff in one place.

I have tried to add/remove scroll flags for some_view inside onScrolled listener for the RecyclerView.
Also I have tried to remove AppBarLayout from fragment and manually collapse some_view inside onScrolled listener for the RecyclerView, but it needs complex logic.

Could you suggest how can I implement my scrolling case in right way?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`CollapsingToolbarLayout`](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

Comment: Could you give example using CollapsingToolbarLayout with two AppBarLayouts?

Comment: I think he means AppBarLayout + CollapsingToolbarLayout + RecyclerView